# Changing last part of URL to be uppercase using htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, case

Not sure if this is a smart way to deal with the problem, which is...

I have a bunch of user dirs that make up a part of their url, eg

```
www.mysite.com/users/USERDIR
```

When I created the site (and since then), user dirs are created using capitals. I wish I hadn't, but it's done. so if someone types in www.mysite.com/users/userdir - it can't find that dir - it has to be in capitals like www.mysite.com/users/USERDIR.

I was wondering....

a) is there a way to tell htaccess "ignore the case when looking for the url?"

or

b) is there a way to deal with this in htaccess, so that no matter what case the user uses, my server will ALWAYS convert the USERDIR to capitals? I need to take into account that some people might type www.mysite.com/users/USERDIR/index.php, and www.mysite.com/users/USERDIR/ with a trailing slash.

I've found some code that converts from lower to upper case letters (below), but is there a way to say "only do this for anything after mysite.com/users/ until either the end or the next slash if one is entered"?

Note - the following does the opposite to what I'm after re case - I just haven't yet recoded it to convert lower to upper.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `a) is there a way to tell htaccess "ignore the case when looking for the url?"`

Yes there is. Use `NC` flag in your rules to for case ignore matching.

> `no matter what case the user uses, my server will ALWAYS convert the USERDIR to capitals?`

If you have access to Apache config then much simpler is to add this line in Apache config:

```
RewriteMap uc int:toupper
```

Then in your .htaccess use this rule to convert your URIs to `upper case`:

```
RewriteRule ^(users)/(.*?[a-z]+.*)$ /$1/${uc:$2} [R,L]
```

Comment: Yes you will need to restart Apache server after changes in `httpd.conf`

Comment: Cheer mate. It's working, but is making everything after the 'users' dir capitals. Is it possible to just make the dir after users capitals, and leave the rest of the url alone, or is that above the call of duty for htaccess? so instead of the rewrite changing users/danny/index.php to users/DANNY/INDEX.php, just changing it to users/DANNY/index.php

Comment: Yes that can be done too. Using this rule: **`RewriteRule ^(users)/(.*?[a-z]+[^/]*)/index\.php$ /$1/${uc:$2}/$3 [R,L]`**

Comment: My mistake - I thought it was working, but it was just my browser remembering different cases. Do I add RewriteMap uc int:toupper directly to httpd.conf?

Comment: Yes that lines needs to be added to httpd.conf and then restart is needed.

Comment: I am looking over the docs now. I also tried adding it to one of the httpd.conf includes, and I ran /usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update. RewriteMap uc int:toupper is definitely appearing in httpd.conf after restart, and other directives in my htaccess work. Am I missing a step? Thanks!

Comment: I have tested this before posting and only 2 steps needed are the ones I posted in my answer. 1) `RewriteMap uc int:toupper` line in httpd.conf and 2) RewriteRule line in main .htaccess

Comment: So that should change https://www.mysite.com/users/JOHNNY1/index.php to https://www.mysite.com/users/johnny1/index.php and  https://www.mysite.com/users/JOHNNY1 to  https://www.mysite.com/users/johnny1 - right?

Comment: No I thought you are trying to do reverse that is to change from lowercase to uppercase since you wrote: `no matter what case the user uses, my server will ALWAYS convert the USERDIR to capitals?` If you want them to convert to lowercase let me know I will update my answer.

Comment: My mistake - I should have said - so that should change mysite.com/users/johnny1 to mysite.com/users/JOHNNY1/index.php to /index.php and mysite.com/users/johnny1 to mysite.com/users/JOHNNY1  - right? – Shaun 14 hours ago

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your last comment. Try clarifying one more time please.